# AD623 in-amp output not making sense

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I'm planning to use the [AD623](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD623.pdf) in-amp for voltage-difference amplification in a project, but I'm having some issues with getting it to work as wanted.

Right now I'm actually just testing the in-amp so that I get to see how it works.

My voltage supply is 7V, my gain resistor is 220k and my input is 3.3V.

With this gain resistor I should get a gain of about 1.5, but my output is at 6.5V (gain = 2.) The output doesn't change even if I change the value of the resistor.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Input voltage range is 1.5V max from data sheet page 5

Answer (score 3):

Try AD's [diamond plot tool](https://tools.analog.com/en/diamond/#difL=3.3&difR=3.3&difSl=3.3&gain=1.5&l=1.65&pr=AD623&r=1.65&sl=1.65&tab=1&ty=1&vn=0&vp=7&vr=0). You can figure this out from the datasheet, but the tool is dead easy to use.

[image]

The name comes from the diamond-shaped plot of allowable Vcm vs Vout typically exhibited when instrumentation amplifiers have bipolar supplies.

Answer (score 1):

The right tool for the job (since it is a Analog Devices INA) is the **diamond plot tool**, which Spehro Pefhany recommended, since the datasheet cannot cover every corner case (with the graphics) regarding the voltage rails.

When you can check that the output OpAmp is not saturated (enough distance from the rails, as specified), there is a way to check if any of the input OpAmps may be saturated when applying large differential voltage.

If you connect a 10 MOhm multimeter across the gain resistor, it will be slightly reduced (to ~215 kOhm), increasing the gain by just 0.7%, so we can disregard it. As you can see, there is no voltage gain in the output stage, so you should measure around 3.3V across the gain resistor. The absolute values of the internal nodes depend on the common mode input voltage.

[image]

If you measure a value below this, try increasing the common mode voltage in your test by applying e.g. ~0.5V (a diode drop with low current) to the inverting input, instead of 0V, while leaving the other input at 3.3V. According to the diamond tool, it should suffice.

**Note:** the new configuration you posted as an answer is within specs, so you should be measuring 1.65V: between the inputs, between the gain resistor pins (now open) and at the output. This is the new operating point:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems: -

- Pin 5 left floating or connected to a voltage source.
- Input of 3.3 volts is floating (need to have a pull-down bias resistor connected).
- The input signal is beyond one of the power rails to the InAmp.
- You have made a mistake wiring it up.
- Your supply is too noisy or not as you expect it to be.
- What you think is a 220 kΩ resistor is smaller (more gain).

Things that are OK: -

- Supply voltage of 7 volts.
- Gain resistor of 220 kΩ produces a gain of 1.454545.
- 3.3 volt input should work OK i.e. it is within the limits of the supply (-Vs-0.15 to +Vs-1.5).
- Anticipated output of 4.8 volts is OK (AD623 InAmp has R2R output).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a dual supply op amp in a single supply application without compensating for the voltage offset produced on its output when using single voltage supply. This device has an voltage offset pin to compensate for this bias offset from using a single supply.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I checked out the sim and tried some of the setups but
I still have the same problem. The setup I have now is the following: Voltage divider to get 1.5V input, Vs = 5V and Rg = open(Gain 1). My output shows 4.3V even though it should be 1.5V
[image: Circuit]

Comment: This configuration is within specs. If you have a digital multimeter (large input resistance, e.g. > 10MEG) you should be able to measure 1.65V between -IN and +IN **and also** between +RG and -RG. If you double checked everything and the output still seems to be always close to +Vs, maybe the component is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment back yet, (new here) but the DC offset on the output must be corrected by using the ref pin when using this op amp with a single supply.

This is the real schematic of the chip. Of course, you should have consulted the datasheet by now. [image]